# Can I get rabies from a stray puppy

Tags: dogs

[image]

I adopted a stray puppy about 2months old. The mom was abandoned near our home our neighbor took in the mom. He likes nipping clothes and shoe ties and I'm worried if I get bitten. Can I get rabies from it? Should I get rabies prevention shot?

Answer (score 1):

So I did a bit of research on rabies.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabies) states that:

> All warm-blooded species, including humans, may become infected with the rabies virus and develop symptoms.

As rabies is transmitted in the saliva

> The virus is usually present in the nerves and saliva of a symptomatic rabid animal.

you can get infected if the puppy is infected.

I have not adopted stray animals but I would take the puppy to the vet as fast as possible and get it checked. The vet can probably also tell you about the possible danger.